# Simple wkhtmltopdf conversion with framesets creating empty pdf

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

We need to convert/provide our html-based in-app HelpSystem to an on-disc pdf for the client to view outside of the application.

I'm trying to use [`wkhtmltopdf`](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) with a very basic file (3 frames with links to simple .html files) but getting an empty `.pdf` when I run the following from the command line:

```
wkhtmltopdf "C:\Program Files (x86)\wkhtmltopdf\index.html" "c:\delme\test.pdf"
```

I know frames are somewhat deprecated but it’s what I’ve got to deal with. Are the frames causing the empty pdf?

Index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Help</title>
  </head>
  <frameset cols="28%, 72%">
    <frameset rows="8%, 92%">
      <frame noresize="noresize" src="Buttons.html" name="UPPERLEFT" />      
      <frame noresize="noresize" src="mytest2.html" name="LOWERLEFT" />
    </frameset>
    <frame noresize="noresize" src="mytest.html" name="RIGHT" />
  </frameset>
</html>
```

mytest.html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>
      <b>This text is bold</b>
    </p>
    <p>
      <strong>This text is strong</strong>
    </p>
    <p>
      <em>This text is emphasized</em>
    </p>
    <p>
      <i>This text is italic</i>
    </p>
    <p>
      <small>This text is small</small>
    </p>
    <p>This is 
    <sub>subscript</sub> and 
    <sup>superscript</sup></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

mytest2.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>The blockquote Element</h2>
    <p>The blockquote element specifies a section that is quoted from another source.</p>
    <p>Here is a quote from WWF&#39;s website:</p>
    <blockquote cite="http://www.worldwildlife.org/who/index.html">For 50 years, WWF has been protecting the future of nature. The
    world’s leading conservation organization, WWF works in 100 countries and is supported by 1.2 million members in the United
    States and close to 5 million globally.</blockquote>
    <p>
    <b>Note:</b> Browsers usually indent blockquote elements.</p>
    <h2>The q Element</h2>
    <p>The q element defines a short quotation.</p>
    <p>WWF&#39;s goal is to: 
    <q>Build a future where people live in harmony with nature.</q> We hope they succeed.</p>
    <p>
    <b>Note:</b> Browsers insert quotation marks around the q element.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

buttons.html:

```
![<html>
  <body>
    <center>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <form method="link" action="mytest.html" target="LOWERLEFT">
              <input type="submit" value="Contents" />
            </form>
          </td>
          <td>
            <form method="link" action="mytest2.html" target="LOWERLEFT">
              <input type="submit" value="Index" />
            </form>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>][2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [the official `wkhtmltopdf` issues area](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=382) from a code project member’s answer; emphasis is mine:

> wkhtmltopdf calculates the TOC based on the H* (e.g. H1, H2 and so on)
>   tags in the supplied documents. **It does not recurse into frames and
>   iframes..** It will nest dependend on the number, to make sure that it
>   does the right thing, it is good to make sure that you only have
>    tags under a  tag and not  for some k larger
>   then 1. 2000+ files sounds like a lot. You might run out of memory
>   while converting the output. If it does not work for you.. you could
>   try using the switch to dump the outline to a xml file, to see what it
>   would but into a TOC.